# Meaning of "this view [is] similar to that which informs the rendering [...], and addresses the same set of concerns that motivated the former"

Tags: meaning-in-context

From the Wikipedia entry on [Swing (Java)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29):

> Conceptually, this view of the layout management is quite similar to
>   that which informs the rendering of HTML content in browsers, and
>   addresses the same set of concerns that motivated the former.

There are a few points I can't understand:

1. What does "informs" mean here?
2. I don't understand "address the same set of concerns that motivated
   the former."

Comment: Have you looked *inform* up in a dictionary? I don't understand why you don't understand the sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at definition 2 from the American Heritage Dictionary of inform, reproduced [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inform).  Swing's view of layout management is similar to the view with which HTML rendering by browsers is imbued.

I think "former" is being used in the chronological sense here, in that browser HTML rendering pre-dates Swing.  That is, the layout management view of Swing and the layout management view of browser HTML rendering were both motivated by the same set of concerns.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand this, but I think your answer has some reasons, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The relevant sense of verb *[inform](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inform#Verb)* is “To give form or character to; to inspire (with a given quality); to affect, influence (with a pervading principle, idea etc.)”.

Your question about what “former” refers to is difficult to answer because the sentence in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29) is unclear.   It might refer to browsers, or to the Java GUI toolkit mentioned in the sentence before the one you quote; but it seems most probable to me that it refers to  relative layouts, mentioned in the first sentence of the paragraph, and apparently the main subject of the whole paragraph:

> ... Swing favors relative layouts (which specify the positional relationships between components) as opposed to absolute layouts (which specify the exact location and size of components).

Comment: Thanks for your patience, I'll try hard to understand it.